# Linear Independence - Sequence

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure how to prove this "we know that two polynomials are equal if and only if all their parameters are equal".

Please tell me if my answer is wrong too.

Show that $\{(1, l,l^2, l^3,... \}\in \mathbb{R}^\infty \colon l \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is linearly independent.

We need to prove that for all in the reals $a_1 \cdot 1 + a_2 \cdot l + a_3 \cdot l^2 + a_4 \cdot l^3 +\dotsc = 0$ iff $a_i = 0$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. We can consider $a_1 \cdot 1 + a_2 \cdot l + a_3 \cdot l^2 + a_4 \cdot l^3 +\dotsc$ as a polynomial and we know that two polynomials are equal if and only if all their parameters are equal, therefore $a_i = 0$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Linearly independet means that teh only FINITE linear combination that is equals zero is the trivial one.

Comment: I do not know if I understood your point, do you mean that this is not linear independent because the list of vectors is infinite?

Comment: Polynomials is a good idea. However, you need to take finitely many different elements of your set, that is finitely (let's say $n$) many sequences $x_k=(1,l_k,l_k^2,l_k^3,\dotsc)$, each given by a different $l_k\in\mathbb{R}$ for $k=1,\dotsc,n$. Then, assume that $a_1x_1+\dotsc+a_nx_n=0$ and show that that implies $a_1=\dotsc=a_n=0$.

Comment: Hi Beaba! Is there any way I can expand my answer to help you better?

Comment: Hello Alex D, I need to study the linear independence of an infinity set of vectors. I did not know that such a concept existed I will take a look and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with by saying $l$ is not in the span of (1) since no linear combination of scalars can equal a degree one polynomial. So $(1,l)$ is a list of linearly independent vectors. Similarly, $l^2$ is not in the span of $(1,l)$ since no linear combination of polynomials of degree less than two can equal a polynomial of degree two. So $(1,l,l^2)$ is a list of linearly independent vectors. Next is $(1,l,l^2,l^3)$, and so on by induction

Also, you can modify the definition of linear independent to include infinite dimensional vector spaces. When we say that a vector space $V$ is generated by or spanned by an infinite set of vectors $\{v_1, v_2, . . . \}$, we mean that each vector $v$ in $V$ is a finite linear combination $\lambda_{i_1} v_{i_1} + · · · + \lambda_{i_n}v_{i_n}$ of the $v_i$ ’s. Likewise, an infinite set of vectors $\{v_1, v_2, . . . \}$ is said to be linearly independent if the only finite linear combination of the $v_i$’s that is zero is the trivial linear combination. So a set $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, . . . , \}$ is a basis for $V$ if and only if every element of $V$ can be be written in a unique way as a finite linear combination of elements from the set.